# Do DLL's reference dependencies need to be extant in order to utilize any class objects from the DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, dependencies, class-library

For example, I have a large class library that does a number of things... I build it into a project.  Some of the class objects depend on "Copyrighted.dll" - but this project is not going to use any of the class objects with "using Copyrighted"...  Will the DLL still be functional for classes that don't depend on that?

I suppose I could try to test this out somehow, but I'm not in a place with the code that it's easy at this moment.

Comment: The CLR loads assemblies on demand, asked to do so by the jitter.  So, technically, if you never ask it to compile code that uses a type from that assembly then it will never fail to load.  The only way to be completely sure that it doesn't is to get to a place in your code where you can make it easy.

Comment: I went ahead and separated the objects that reference the copyrighted DLL (UnityEngine.dll) and the ones that don't...  I like the idea of keeping my entire personal class library in one DLL, but it's probably best not to cause problems.  If I ship the DLL with a Unity game, it's not a problem, but there's plenty of non-Unity sourced class objects for use in standard applications.